# My AJAX Application always returns "found"

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to do a really simple task: check if an inserted id matches one found in a mysql database.  If no match, an alert box will appear displaying an invalid id message.  The problem that I have is my script ALWAYS returns found, even if the id does not exist in the database.  Here is my script, any idea what is wrong?

PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php
//connect to server....

$id = $_GET["id"];

$query = 'SELECT * from users where id = $id';
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);

if (empty($result))
{
$response = "notfound";
echo $response;
}
else
{
$response = "found";
echo $response;
}


// Close connection to the database
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Probably because the MySQL server still returns something, even if there's no result... In addition, `$query = 'SELECT * from users where id = $id';` should be `$query = 'SELECT * from users where id =' . $id;`, assuming that you've escaped `$id`, of course.

Comment: Escape your SQL or I shall pwn your webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$query = 'SELECT * from users where id = '.(int) $id;
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows > 0) {
echo "found";
}
else {
 echo "not found";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using single quotes instead of double quotes on your query assignment. You must use double quotes or string concatenating.

```
$query = "SELECT * from users where id = $id";
```

**OR**

```
$query = 'SELECT * from users where id = ' . $id;
```

And you're also probably doing this in the insert, which is why it's always being 'found'.

Comment: in that case shouldnt his query always return not found??

Comment: @Baz1nga That's due to the (incorrect) use of `empty()`. The result won't be empty, so she can check using `mysql_num_rows` or simply `if($result)`

Answer (score 0):

I am no  t familiar with php syntax but can you replace the if condition to be something like this

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);
if($result)
{
$response = "found";
echo $response;
}
else
{
$response = "notfound";
echo $response;
}
```